# HTML5 data DOM's change isn't seen by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using HTML5's `data` to store some informations on a `div` on my website, and whenever I change the value of this data with jQuery, the DOM's updating well, but jQuery **doesn't see** the update when I try to retrieve the value.

I update the value of this data with `$('#myDiv').attr('data-my_data',value);`, and get the value back with `$('#myDiv').data('data-my_data')`.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLJKa/) to illustrate my problem.

Is this happening because of some jQuery's initial representation of the DOM that doesn't update?

I don't get it, any help will be appreciated!

*Configuration : Chrome 25 - jQuery 1.9.0 - Mac OSx 10.7*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the values to the `data('yourKey','Yourvalue')`

```
$(yourElement).data('isEdit','1');
```

according to your Example

```
$('#myDiv').data('data-my_data','value');
```

Attr : it will add attributges to the dom object.

prop : it will add properites in memory.  so your data will be stroed in dataSet of DOM.

for more info check this [attr vs prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 1):

`data-*` attributes are mapped to `dataset` DOMString object, use `data` method as **setter**, do not use `attr` for properties.

```
$('#testDiv').data('test_data', newData).html("My data is : " + newData);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zgKdg/

Comment: Thank you, it works! But why jQuery doesn't see the change of the dataset DOMString object?

Comment: @Bigood Because `data-*` attribute actually is a property, modifying attributes doesn't change the properties.

Comment: @Bigood check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr this for more info